# Content of div affects horizontal alignment, inline-block issue

Tags: css

I'm struggling a bit with this CSS-issue: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/JbEX8/

I want two divs to align horizontally using "display: inline-block", however when I add text to one of the divs, the alignment is off.

Is there a way to make the two divs align without resorting to floats?

This is my markup:

```
<div class="box">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div><!-- /box -->

<div class="box">
    <!-- No text -->
</div><!-- /box -->
```

This is my CSS:

```
body {
color: gray;
}

.box {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;   
}
```

Check out my example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/JbEX8/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `vertical-align` to class `box`:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Also see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JbEX8/5/).

Answer (score 3):

You should `float` them:

```
.box {
    float: left;

    background: #ccc;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;   
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JbEX8/1/**

Do note that since you didn't define margins, there is no spacing between them.