# Why my inline-block divs are not aligned when only one of them has text?

Tags: html, alignment, css

> *Live page [here](http://jsbin.com/oqodol/1/edit).*

Given this HTML page:

```css
section[role=main] {
  margin: 1em;
  width: 95%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

section[role=main] article {
  width: 40%;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section role="main">
  <article>Java</article>
  <article></article>
</section>

<section role="main">
  <article>Java</article>
  <article>JavaScript</article>
</section>
```

I expect both of my articles to be aligned, but as it can be seen in the screenshot below, only when both of my articles have text the `<article>` elements are center aligned:

[image: alignment issue]

Any ideas what is causing this behavior and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Adding `&nbsp;` in the empty article fixes it, but I'm looking into a better solution.

Comment: @bookcasey I know, but I am wondering what is causing this behavior in the first place.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is the consequence of the "baseline" vertical alignment in CSS. From the [CSS 2.1 spec, section 10.8 Line height calculations: the 'line-height' and 'vertical-align' properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)

> ### baseline
>
> > Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. **If the box 
> >     does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with the parent's baseline.** (my emphasis)

Because the default alignment for the inline-blocks is "baseline", unless it is overridden, this rule applies. When text is put in the inline-block, that text will create a baseline for the inline-block and the first (non-bolded) sentence applies.

When there is no text in the inline-block, then it has no baseline and so the second (bolded) sentence applies.

In the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WjCb9/1/ I have removed from your example the `margin:1em` which was creating (at least for me) a misleading illusion, and added the text `baseline` to show where the baseline of the containing box is. The baseline is along the bottom of the word "baseline", so you can see that the empty inline-block has its bottom margin edge aligned with the parent's baseline as required by the CSS rule above.

Answer (score 65):

Adding:

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

To your second rule should make it work. Apparently, inline-blocks with no text are rendered as inline-images or something else, and the vertical-align of these elements are incorrect, so forcing them to be aligned to bottom fixes the issue.

Source: [inline-block element with no text renders differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053575/css-inline-block-element-with-no-text-renders-differently)

Comment: thanks, but why is it needed in the first place? A more official/formal explanation would be helpful.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Comment: this works better, I think

Answer (score 8):

clone of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967497/content-of-div-affects-horizontal-alignment-inline-block-issue)

Add vertical-align to article:

```
section[role=main] article { 
  ...
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/oqodol/6/edit

Answer (score 2):

The `inline-block` elements are positioned by the `text-align` of their parent.

If there is no text within the block, there is nothing to align.

You can solve this problem by using `display: block;` and floats, or my suggestion is to insert a non-breaking, zero-width space with pseudo elements:

```
section[role=main] article:before {
  content: "\2060";
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/oqodol/2/)