# Why element has various height depending on whether it has content or not

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

I am curious to know why following elements have various heights:

```html
<i class="icon"></i>
<i class="noicon"></i>
```

```css
i {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}

i.icon:before   { content: 'Ω'; }
i.noicon:before { content: '';  }
```

That case may be illustrated by http://jsfiddle.net/pJw9d/ (hover the symbols with pointer to view the difference in sizes).

---

*PS: I know how to fix such problem (e.g., by using non-breaking space (`&nbsp;` or `\00a0`), or by defining CSS positions), but I would like to know why it behaves that way.*

Comment: It is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548168/why-my-inline-block-divs-are-not-aligned-when-only-one-of-them-has-text/13550706#13550706

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *[@anddoutoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98378/anddoutoi)* correctly pointed, that behavior is explained in **[W3C Recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)**:

> If the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with the parent's baseline.

**[That fiddle demonstrates](http://jsfiddle.net/aV8fL/)**, that it is not that empty element's size increases, but that it is *risen* for the baseline `height`.

---

Such jumps can be avoided either

- by replacing the empty content with *non-breaking space*, e.g.:

```css
    i.noicon:before { content: '\00a0'; }
```

- or by defining the `vertical-align` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "vertical-align" to your css attributes for i:

```
i {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 1em;
   height: 1em;
   background: green;
   vertical-align: top; //add this
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJw9d/1/)

Comment: But the question is "Why?", not how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @Pedro, but I would like to rather understand CSS behavior on empty content rather than fix current example.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please let me know [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pJw9d/3/) is what you need?

**html**

```
<div><i class="icon"></i><i class="noicon"></i></div>
<div><i class="icon"></i></div>
```

**css**

```
body {
    font-size: 2em;
}
div {
    float:left;
}
i {
    display: block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: green;
    float:left;
}
i.icon:before {
    content:'Ω';
}
i.icon:hover:before {
    content:'';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ilmk, but I would like to rather understand CSS behavior on empty content rather than fix current example.

Comment: for empty block, you need to use float:left so that given width and height will take place correctly. Thanks.