# Alignment Issue :- Second Post is not aligned properly

Tags: html, css

i am facing an alignment issue for which i have a solution.
But i wanted to know the reason behind this.
If u run the html markup which i have provided you can see that the second post is not inline with the first post.

I wanted second post to align with first post. I have the solution by using flex.But i need reason and not the solution

HTML :-

```
<div class="_3yTtBPc-LMIvY20o00OVsF">
  <div class="_2wIS4xHyz03D-DXLdHPFxP">
    <div class="_2NwLO4_WeKC2-xigIODSyO" style="">sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit</div>
    <div>Nik</div>
  </div>
  <div class="_2wIS4xHyz03D-DXLdHPFxP">
    <div class="_2NwLO4_WeKC2-xigIODSyO" style="
    /* min-height: 90px; */
">qui est esse</div>
    <div>Nik</div>
  </div>
  <div class="_2wIS4xHyz03D-DXLdHPFxP">
    <div class="_2NwLO4_WeKC2-xigIODSyO">ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut</div>
    <div>Nik</div>
  </div>
  <div class="_2wIS4xHyz03D-DXLdHPFxP">
    <div class="_2NwLO4_WeKC2-xigIODSyO">eum et est occaecati</div>
    <div>Nik</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :-

```
._3yTtBPc-LMIvY20o00OVsF {
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

._2wIS4xHyz03D-DXLdHPFxP {
  width: 90px;
  height: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 0 lightgrey;
}

._2NwLO4_WeKC2-xigIODSyO {
  max-height: 90px;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

expected :- second post should be in line with first post
actual :- second post is bit down that first post.

Comment: Possible duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548168/why-my-inline-block-divs-are-not-aligned-when-only-one-of-them-has-text

Comment: Possible duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward

Answer (score 2):

By default when you use the `display:inline-block;` you are using a `vertical-align: baseline;`
You can see a similar problem at this url:

[Why my inline-block divs are not aligned when only one of them has text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548168/why-my-inline-block-divs-are-not-aligned-when-only-one-of-them-has-text)

You need to add explicitly `vertical-align: top`, in order to align the blocks relative to their tops, otherwise the alignment will be done based on the baselines of the internal divs, as you see on the image.[image: Vertical-align: baseline]

Comment: i had one question though, vertical-align:baseline uses parent baseline how come it is taking child divs baseline.

Comment: I am still thinking about it too. An other very similar problem answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-block-element-pushed-downward

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `vertical-align: top;`

```
._2wIS4xHyz03D-DXLdHPFxP {
  width: 90px;
  height: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 0 lightgrey;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```